# How to get the image data from void click function?

Tags: c++, function, opencv, onclick, void

I have finished the click_function reading image from any files using Browse_button in GUI. Now I need another click_function to process this image but I don't know how to get image data from the previous click_function. Please help me to solve this problem.
This is all file and source code:

```
1. mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <QPushButton>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QPushButton* htest;

private slots:
    void on_Image_Open_clicked();
    void on_pixel_add_button_clicked();
    void on_pixel_add_button_clicked(bool checked);
    void on_pixel_add_button_toggled(bool checked);
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

2. main.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

3. mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{    
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_Image_Open_clicked() {

    QString filename=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Choose"),"",tr("Images(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp *.gif)"));    
    
    //read from file
    Mat img=cv::imread(filename.toLatin1().data()); //read image with [(B:width x height)(G:widthxheight)(R:widthxheight)

    //convert to RGB to show on Gui
    Mat orgb_img;
    cvtColor(img,orgb_img,CV_BGR2RGB);

    //display original image on first window (image will be resized to 256x256 as Gui config)
    QImage imdisplay((uchar*)orgb_img.data, orgb_img.cols, orgb_img.rows, orgb_img.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    ui->original_image->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(imdisplay)); 
}
```

... and my next click_function to process this image may like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_pixel_add_button_clicked()
{

    how can I get all image data here to process?. 
    ...process command...
}
```

Comment: Store the data in member variables.

Comment: Mat img=cv::imread(filename.toLatin1().data());

The image is loaded in this variable "img" of type Mat.
Instead of local variable(MAT img), create a variable in your class "MainWindow", like Mat m_img, or put it as a global variable on the top of the .cpp file
and use it :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja: please explain with more details.

Comment: show us the class definition of `MainWindow` (edit your post to include the code). that is where you will add a line or two.

Comment: I fixed it. The code runs ok now! Just add 'on_pixel_add_button_clicked(img);' in on_Image_Open_clicked() function and define 'void MainWindow:: on_pixel_add_button_clicked(cv::Mat& pxadd_img)'